# search in json data in the database codeigniter

Tags: mysql, json, codeigniter

i have a database that saves the data into json and a column named delivery_status like this

```
[{"vendor":"1002","status":"on_delivery","delivery_time":""}]
```

now after getting the status from it and displaying it i need to search in a form for the status my query is like this

```
  $delivery_status = json_encode($this->input->post("delivery_status"));                
 $page_data['sale']  = $this->db//->like('status', $status)
               ->query("select * from sale where sale_datetime BETWEEN " . "'" .$date1. "'" . " AND " . "'" . $date2 . "'")
                ->result_array();
```

my view

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="status" class="col-sm-2 control-label">status</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select  class="form-control width-r" name="payment_status">
                    <option>
                        <?php
                        $statuss = $this->db->query("SELECT  delivery_status FROM sale")->result_array();
                        foreach ($statuss as $status) {
                            $statu = json_decode($status['delivery_status']);

                            foreach ($statu as $ro) {
                                ?>
                            <option>

                                <?php echo $ro->status; ?>
                            </option>

                        <?php }
                    } ?>


                </select>

            </div>
        </div>
```

but there is no results.

Comment: Unclear...Explain clearly what issue you are facing

Comment: zeeshan i have a column in the database that is saved in json  i was successful at displaying the data but now i need to search the output using like how can i do that